# Installing MongoDB C++ driver on Windows.

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mongodb, mingw

How can I compile and link a MongoDB C++ driver in Windows? I would like to use Mongodb in Qt for MinGW.

Comment: What problems are you having a what have you tried? You need to first compile the drivers, then link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See 10gen's [C++ driver build instructions](https://wiki.10gen.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21266598). There is a section for building on Windows.

Comment: this is behind a login wall